# Is maven-release-plugin compatible with Java 9?

Tags: java, maven-3, maven-release-plugin, java-9, maven-compiler-plugin

I just tried to release my Java 9 compatible project with `maven-release-plugin`. However, it failed in `maven-compiler-plugin` with

> Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile
>   (default-compile) on project email: Fatal error compiling: invalid
>   target release: 9

Funny thing is that `maven-compiler-plugin` works fine in case I run it standalone.
My setup:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>9</source>
                <target>9</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
                <tagNameFormat>v@{project.version}</tagNameFormat>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Maven version 3.5.0.

`mvn clean install` works fine;

`mvn release:prepare release:perform -DignoreSnapshots=true` fails with above exception.

Debug output:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.3:prepare (default-cli) on project blynk: Maven execution failed, exit code: '1' -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.3:prepare (default-cli) on project blynk: Maven execution failed, exit code: '1'
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:993)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:345)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:191)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Maven execution failed, exit code: '1'
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.release.PrepareReleaseMojo.prepareRelease(PrepareReleaseMojo.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.release.PrepareReleaseMojo.execute(PrepareReleaseMojo.java:240)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.shared.release.ReleaseExecutionException: Maven execution failed, exit code: '1'
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.AbstractRunGoalsPhase.execute(AbstractRunGoalsPhase.java:91)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.RunPrepareGoalsPhase.execute(RunPrepareGoalsPhase.java:44)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.prepare(DefaultReleaseManager.java:234)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.prepare(DefaultReleaseManager.java:169)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.prepare(DefaultReleaseManager.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.prepare(DefaultReleaseManager.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.release.PrepareReleaseMojo.prepareRelease(PrepareReleaseMojo.java:286)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.shared.release.exec.MavenExecutorException: Maven execution failed, exit code: '1'
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.exec.InvokerMavenExecutor.executeGoals(InvokerMavenExecutor.java:433)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.exec.AbstractMavenExecutor.executeGoals(AbstractMavenExecutor.java:114)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.AbstractRunGoalsPhase.execute(AbstractRunGoalsPhase.java:85)
    ... 30 more

[INFO] [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) on project email: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 9 -> [Help 1]
[INFO] org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) on project email: Fatal error compiling
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:309)
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:194)
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:107)
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:993)
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:345)
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:191)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[INFO]  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[INFO]  at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
[INFO]  at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
[INFO]  at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
[INFO]  at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[INFO] Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Fatal error compiling
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:1086)
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:168)
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
[INFO]  ... 20 more
[INFO] Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.CompilerException: invalid target release: 9
[INFO]  at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavaxToolsCompiler.compileInProcess(JavaxToolsCompiler.java:173)
[INFO]  at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.performCompile(JavacCompiler.java:174)
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:1075)
[INFO]  ... 23 more
[INFO] Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid target release: 9
[INFO]  at com.sun.tools.javac.main.OptionHelper$GrumpyHelper.error(OptionHelper.java:103)
[INFO]  at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Option$12.process(Option.java:216)
[INFO]  at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool.processOptions(JavacTool.java:217)
[INFO]  at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool.getTask(JavacTool.java:156)
[INFO]  at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool.getTask(JavacTool.java:107)
[INFO]  at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool.getTask(JavacTool.java:64)
[INFO]  at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavaxToolsCompiler.compileInProcess(JavaxToolsCompiler.java:125)
[INFO]  ... 25 more
```

Comment: But it works without `maven-release-plugin`.

Comment: Could you share the failure logs of the build in that case with more details. using `-X` debug mode.

Comment: Good point. Added.

Comment: Could you try specifying the `<release>9</release>` in compiler-plugin configuration.

Comment: I tried before and got `Fatal error compiling: invalid flag: --release`

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the same on a project of mine. Please add a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for the same. Also do share the maven configuraiton detailed after executing the `mvn -version` from the command prompt.

Comment: Hm... Seems like issue reproduced only when running maven from Intellij Idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Java+9+-+Jigsaw](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Java+9+-+Jigsaw) which was updated very recently there is no change required or desired in the `maven-release-plugin` to be compatible with JDK9.

Additionally from the logs shared in the question the output in your case seems to be because of a misconfigured Maven with *Java version less than 9*.

---

While I was facing a similar issue, I had noticed that the java version used by Maven when executed using `sudo` and normally on command prompt were different.

---

To stick to consistent version of java used by maven make sure you have a `mavenrc` configured. You can do that in a similar way to this:

```
vi ~/.mavenrc
```

and then save it with content as follows:

```
export PATH
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.jdk/Contents/Home
export PATH=${PATH}:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

---

Execute

```
mvn -version
```

and make sure its output is consistent via both *command prompt* and *intelliJ terminal.*

Answer (score 0):

========== If you use heroku ===========

Go to system.properties and set:

```
java.runtime.version=9
```

Also add the following to the pom.xml for maven:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>9</source>
        <target>9</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Check [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/1263) out.